# How to Generate a Link to download a File in asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, download

I am testing [Doddle Report](http://www.codeplex.com/doddlereport) to generate a few report form a IEnumerable object. I need to generate a Link like this

```
PDF - http://myserver.com/reports/ProductsReport.pdf
```

The Question is how do I do this?

En Stop Using Doddle Report, and generate del Excel in XML format.

Comment: What about this link that you want to generate?  Just the URL, or the actual download link?

Comment: I need to generate the link and then call a Action in my controller.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Check out this [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/aspnet-mvc-controllers-overview-cs) to return different action result.

The ASP.NET MVC framework supports several types of action results including:

- ViewResult – Represents HTML and
  markup.
- EmptyResult – Represents no result.
- RedirectResult – Represents a
  redirection to a new URL.
- JsonResult – Represents a JavaScript
  Object Notation result that can be
  used in an AJAX application.
- JavaScriptResult – Represents a
  JavaScript script.
- ContentResult – Represents a text
  result.
- FileContentResult – Represents a
  downloadable file (with the binary
  content).
- FilePathResult – **Represents a
  downloadable file** (with a **path**).
- FileStreamResult – Represents a
  downloadable file (with a file
  stream).

Comment: The included link is dead. I think the page that it used to refer to can be found here. http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/aspnet-mvc-controllers-overview-cs

Answer (score 6):

I'd done something similar what you want on MVC 5 and I used FilePathResult as J.W said.

cshtml:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Download Here", "DownloadExampleFiles", "Product", new { fileName = "variation-example" }, new { @target = "_blank" })
```

ProductController:

```
public FilePathResult DownloadExampleFiles(string fileName)
{
    return new FilePathResult(string.Format(@"~\Files\{0}", fileName + ".txt"), "text/plain");
}
```

Download a file seems to be very silly/easy, however, for those who are new on MVC, it's not. This approach sounds to be the best while using MVC.

PS: I've forced a .txt just as an example. You should do what is intersting for you to get the specific file.

Comment: I am curious if this might lead to a security issue?  If i call the controller with fileName of something like "..\App_Data\secretfile.mdf" would that let me circumvent security and access a directory I normally couldn't access?  Of course this would rely on knowing the file names and where they are on the server (or a lot of trial and error).  Looks like a nice solution otherwise.

Comment: Yeah you are right, I did it very fast just as an example, but it's not a good idea to send the whole file as a parameter even though I believe you should not have important files in a folder that you are allowing people to download files. I updated the example with a forced .txt =)

Comment: nice and simple. I just had to add setting the FileDownloadName property and this was a perfect solution

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is nothing special about doing this in MVC.  Create a LinkButton on your form with a handler that generates the PDF file, then redirect to the created file.

Comment: Then the file could be opened in browser instead of make it **DOWNLOADABLE**

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe:

```
<h2>List Of Reports</h2>
<ul>
    <% foreach (var report in Model){ %>
        <li><a href="<%= Html.BuildUrlFromExpression<ReportController>(r => r.Reports(report.Filename)) %>"><%=report.Filename %></a></li>
    <% } %>
</ul>
```

There maybe a shorter way but this works.