# How to create downloadable file links in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I make downloadable file links in asp.net mvc for downloading the files?

Also how can I show the file as thumbnail in my page in asp.net mvc?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Generate a Link to download a File in asp.net MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/745042/how-to-generate-a-link-to-download-a-file-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a FileResult. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.fileresult.aspx